# pass Dynamic Html element based on options from parent to child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-dynamic-components

I want to pass html element from parent to child based on conditions like
  **If user click button in parent child should display button** or 
  **If user select chckbox then child should display checkbox** This is my scenario

To solve this I am using **ngTemplateOutlet**,  **ngContent** through content projection concepts in angular.

I am getting error in console **ERROR
Error: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function**

I tried like this

```
  <button (click)="getType('button')">Display button in child</button>
  <div>
  <label>checkbox</label>
  <input type="checkbox" (change)="getType('checkbox')">
  </div>
  <app-child>

  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="dynamicElement"></ng-container>

        <ng-template #tp2>
        <button>Hey I am button passed dynamically from parent</button>
        </ng-template>

          <ng-template #tp3>
        <label>I am checkbox passed from parent</label>
       <input type="checkbox" (change)="getType('checkbox')">
        </ng-template>
```

Please find link I work out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzzsgs-dnfgaq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Is there any other way?

Any help will appreciable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your code as following:

```
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('tp2') public readonly tp2;
  @ViewChild('tp3') public readonly tp3;

  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  dynamicElement: any;
  heroes = [
    new Hero(1, 'Windstorm'),
    new Hero(13, 'Bombasto'),
    new Hero(15, 'Magneta'),
    new Hero(20, 'Tornado')
  ];
  myHero = this.heroes[0];

  getType (type) {
    console.log(type);
    if (type == 'button') {
      this.dynamicElement = this.tp2;
    } else {
      this.dynamicElement = this.tp3;
    }
  }
}
```

You need to import ViewChild directive from '@angular/core' by the way and with it get Ref's from the template for passing it to the ngTemplateOutlet

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar
yes man, link is attached: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzzsgs-hcwd1m?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `@ViewChild` concept; for further info check its [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild). The docs have an example of a countdown component where a parent starts its child every time the parent itself is started.